# herokuでgoogle cloud storageにアクセスできない

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

## 質問

expressを使用しています。
herokuでgoogle cloud storageにファイルをアップロードしようとしてもできません。
以下の場所でエラー文を吐きます。

```js
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream()
```

しかしながら、ローカルでは問題なく動くため、gcsのキーの設定がおかしいと思っています。

```
/api
  index.js //ここで動かしている
```

```
// Procfile
echo ${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS} > /google-credentials.json
web: nuxt start
```

```js
// index.js
const sto = new Storage()
```

```
//env
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:google-credentials.json
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS:"鍵"
```

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALSを設定していれば、new Storage()の時に何も必要ないのでしょうか。
もしくはファイルの指定がおかしいのでしょうか?
よろしくお願いいたします。

### エラー文

```sh
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864878+00:00 app[web.1]: Unexpected end of JSON input
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864890+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864891+00:00 app[web.1]: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864892+00:00 app[web.1]: at ReadStream.<anonymous> (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:334:39)
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864893+00:00 app[web.1]: at ReadStream.emit (events.js:326:22)
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864894+00:00 app[web.1]: at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864894+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
2020-12-06T12:48:41.864895+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

## バージョン

nodejs : 12.19.0
express : 4.17.1

Answer (score 0):

以下で指定している環境変数の`GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS`がJSONではないため、JSON.parseがエラーを吐いているように見えます。

```sh
echo ${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS} > /google-credentials.json
```

`GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS`は`JSON.parse`可能なテキストが保持されているか確認してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

お騒がせしました。
そもそも

```php
echo ${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS} > /app/google-credentials.json
```

であり、保存するファイルは.procfileでした。